# javascript - var in method call not redefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I've written a code which works perfectly but when I switch hardcoded parameters to a variable I get stuck with a problem which I understand but I don't have an idea how to resolve. Also, I am not aware if there is any kind of pattern which could resolve this.

```
var IsIframeAdded = (function(){

    var nr_of_elem = 0;
    var elem;

    events.subscribe( elem + "Loaded", function(length){
        disableIframes(elem);
        nr_of_elem = length;
    });
    //events.subscribe() must be placed above checkIfElemAdded()


    var checkIfElemAdded = function() {
        elem = functional.scripts[0].class;  //Change-set the value of elem variable

        if ( is_page() || is_page('shop') || is_page('portfolio') || is_page('fl-studio-song-starter') ) {
            domCallback.isElemAdded( elem, nr_of_elem ); //check if iframe is added to the DOM
        }
    };


    events.subscribe( "JSONloaded", checkIfElemAdded );
    events.subscribe( "loadMoreClicked", checkIfElemAdded );

})(); // !isIframeAdded


$('.music-portfolio-query').on('click', '.showmore-btn', function(){
    events.publish( "loadMoreClicked" );
});
    enter code here
```

*As I have marked with a comment in code I  must keep events.subscribe() above function called checkIfElemAdded. That way I avoid using setTimeout() on response from domCallBack.isElemAdded()*

**I have mentioned that I understand the problem so I will try to describe it:**

Events.subscribe() doesn't listen to the correct event name.

Problem is with elem variable in events.subscribe() method call
That variable is set on script load which is too early for variable to be set with an element that is pulled from JSON file.
Variable elem  in that call should be loaded after JSONloaded event.
( I am trying to avoid setTimeout solutions )

Are there any developers experienced enough to help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it's probably a duplicate of "how do I return from an async call". I'm not sure though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thanks, I will study it...

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you're asking, but I'm guessing `events.subscribe` is async, so it's callback isn't run immediately. If you're trying to read `elem` before the `checkIfElemAdded` callback is run, it won't have been given a value yet.

Comment: Procedure is like this: 
1. When AJAX is done, it publishes JSONloaded to Observer.
2. Subscriber picks that and invokes a function named checkIfElemAdded.
3. Var elem gets changed.
4. Methode domCallback.isElemAdded() gets invoked
5. Methode domCallback.isElemAdded() publishes elem+"Loaded" name to Observer.
6. Events.subscribe should listen/pick that elem + "Loaded".

But it seems that it is listening to undefined+"Loaded" instead of elem + "Loaded".

Am I right?

Comment: I think that, maybe, hm, good question would be: Is there a way to postpone defining events.subscribe() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself so if anyone would need it, here it is.

```
var IsIframeAdded = (function(){

    var nr_of_elem = 0;
    var elem;

    var checkIfElemAdded = function() {
        elem = functional.scripts[0].class;  //Change-set the value of elem variable


        events.subscribe( elem + "Loaded", function(length){
            disableIframes(elem);
            nr_of_elem = length;
        });
        //events.subscribe() must be placed above domCallback.isElemAdded()


        if ( is_page() || is_page('shop') || is_page('portfolio') || is_page('fl-studio-song-starter') ) {
            domCallback.isElemAdded( elem, nr_of_elem ); //check if iframe is added to the DOM
        }
    };


    events.subscribe( "JSONloaded", checkIfElemAdded );
    events.subscribe( "loadMoreClicked", checkIfElemAdded );

})(); // !isIframeAdded


$('.music-portfolio-query').on('click', '.showmore-btn', function(){
    events.publish( "loadMoreClicked" );
});
```